ACL error after migration from Windows Server 2019 to 2022
When trying to grant rights to folders/files created before moving to a new version of the Windows server, an error occurs
Set-Acl: Some or all identity references could not be translated.
After checking, the following was found out
Get-Acl "path" | Format-List
Path: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::path
Owner: WIN-O5U91U55E36\user
Group: G:S-1-5-21-236285398-2762608689-3265478705-513
Access: WIN-O5U91U55E36\user Allow FullControl
Can anyone tell me how to safely change the Group sid, since I can't find information anywhere?
I tried to fix it through built-in cmdlets and through SetACLstudio
